# bundler installs the country_select gem from the wrong source

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, bundler

In my Rail 3.2.13 gemfile I have added the country_select gem

```
gem 'country_select', :git => 'git://github.com/stefanpenner/country_select.git'
```

Rrunning bundle install however loads the wrong version of the gem. It instead loads the out-dated repository at https://github.com/rails/country_select

This happens in my development environment as well as when deploying my app to Heroku.

I was able to overcome this in my dev environment by using the ruby gem specific_install however that doesn't help with heroku.

Any ideas?

Comment: what is the version in your gemfile.lock?

Comment: country_select (1.2.0) - the latest version

Comment: is it from this git source 'git://github.com/stefanpenner/country_select.git' or the other one ?

Comment: GIT
  remote: git://github.com/stefanpenner/country_select.git
  revision: be3618c7c6c9b4a37dea736404b78917fd5ff748
  specs:
    country_select (1.2.0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to update your Gemfile.lock with the git path:

```
bundle update country_select
```

It should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the branch you want to use on the remote git repository using:

```
gem 'country_select', :git => 'git://github.com/stefanpenner/country_select.git', branch: 'master'
```

or event a commit tag:

```
gem 'country_select', :git => 'git://github.com/stefanpenner/country_select.git', revision: 'commit_tag_here'
```

Beside, when running in Production, a good practice is to **fix** your gem versions in order to avoid unwanted gem updates.